# Using datatable for reportviewer c#

Tags: c#, report, reportviewer

I am new at creating report . After following through MSDN I have created a table and attached it to reportViewer but it does not show anything . Is there I am doing anything wrong way ?

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("myDataset");

// create datatable
DataTable dt = new DataTable("myDatatable");

                // add columns
dt.Columns.Add("column1", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("column2", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("column3", typeof(string));

// insert data rows
dt.Rows.Add("row1-col1", "row1-col2", "row1-col3");
dt.Rows.Add("row2-col1", "row2-col2", "row2-col3");



ds.Tables.Add(dt);





BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = ds;


ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
rds.Name = "dsBody";
rds.Value = ds.Tables["myDatatable"] ;


reportViewer1.Reset();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\Temp\Report1.rdlc";
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Show us a snippet of the \Report1.rdlc file? Specifically the dsBody part, all your DataSet & DataTable code looks fine.

Comment: Report1.rdlc is blank , I am supposed to attach the data through datatable at runtime , Have I missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

This QA has the solution, like I was saying you need a Tablix in the rdlc file that you can bind your DataTable to dynamically.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22196065

Open up Business Intelligence Studio (it's included with Sql Server Reporting Services) and insert a Tablix control into a report, then tweak the data source properties of the Tablix/grid to match the name of your DataTable, save it and check the XML in the rdlc file.

Once you get all that sorted it should start working (you may encounter some strange error messages- but persist), start off basic to get basic data populated in your report. Then finish it up with your production report.